# Having difficulties getting my vhosts to work properly

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, apache-http-server, ubuntu-server

I have my URL (example.com:8010) pointing to my server, which works and goes to the /var/www directory properly.  I created another vhost file to go to the test directory but when I type the URL for that in with a subdomain it does not work (test.example.com:8010), only typing it in with a slash works (example.com:8010/test).

EDIT: Something I forgot to mention is that when I *do* go to test.example.com:8010 it goes to the default /var/www folder, and that typing text.example.com:8010/test obviously goes to the test folder.

Here is my vhost for the two entries:

Example.com -

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory /var/www/>
                AllowOverride All
                Order Deny,Allow
                Allow from All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8010>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory /var/www/>
                AllowOverride All
                Order Deny,Allow
                Allow from All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Test.Example.com -

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test.example.com
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/test
        <Directory /var/www/test/>
                AllowOverride All
                Order Deny,Allow
                Allow from All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8010>
        ServerName test.example.com
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/test
        <Directory /var/www/test/>
                AllowOverride All
                Order Deny,Allow
                Allow from All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I should also mention that I have another vhost for that test directory set up so that on my local network i can type test.lacol and it goes to that directory, which works:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName test.lacol
            ServerAdmin admin@example.com
            DocumentRoot /var/www/test
            <Directory /var/www/test/>
                    AllowOverride All
                    Order Deny,Allow
                    Allow from All
            </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:8010>
            ServerName test.lacol
            ServerAdmin admin@example.com
            DocumentRoot /var/www/test
            <Directory /var/www/test/>
                    AllowOverride All
                    Order Deny,Allow
                    Allow from All
            </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to enable the site.

> sudo a2ensite example.com

Answer (score 0):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Looks like you have `<VirtualHost> *:80>` spelled incorrectly. Should be `<VirtualHost *:80>`

Comment: Fixed the formatting but it did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured yous site at `/etc/hosts`? If you have, look at your `php.ini` and look for your `open_basedir` configuration. `open_basedir, if set, limits all file operations to the defined directory and below`.

If it is not defined, look at your `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. Maybe it can help you.